# How to display current machine informations in terminal?

Tags: terminal

Is there a command line to see what computer I'm actually on ?

I extensively use terminals, and my PS1 between sessions and computers are alike so I get confused what machine I am currently using. By machine I mean local computer or server, not the current user (because the PS1 is showing this information). Is there a command line for that ?

(ps: I request a command line, not how to change the PS1 because sometimes I am working on a small screen and I try to manage relatively short lines)

thanks

Comment: I don't think this question has a reliable general answer, but localised answers are of course possible. Hostnames can be the same, the same goes for IP addresses, and even MACs. HDDs UUIDs or MB SN are possibly unique, but usually not human usable for this purpose

Comment: @Fox thanks, perfect, this is what I wanted.

Comment: Does not your terminal prompt include the hostname OOB? What UNIX system are you running and what is your shell?

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, the prompt is the best thing to use to remind you of where you are. It can be used to remind you about the machine, the current user name, the directory etc.  The prompt is always there on the command line, so it will be difficult to ignore it. Using some other *command* to look up what the current machine name is (like `hostname`) will obviously also work, but you'll forget to do it.

---

Set your primary prompt to a string that includes the host name:

```
PS1="$(id -un)@$(hostname) \$ "
```

This will, on my current machine, and for my user, set the prompt to

```
kk@client.local $
```

You may want to use `hostname -s` instead of just `hostname` to remove the domain part of the host name.

Some shells, like `bash`, have shorthand notations that you may use for the same thing.  For `bash` (replace `\H` with `\h` to get the shorter version of the host name):

```
PS1='\u@\H \$ '
```

Note that there is no need to `export` `PS1` as it's only used by the current shell process.

Changes to this variable may be done in your shell initialization file.  For `bash`, modify `~/.bashrc`.  Read your shell's manual about `PS1`.

---

For really small screens, you may want to come up with your own dynamic prompt:

```
case "$(hostname)" in
    bigserver*)  promptstr='bs'  ;;
    srv-*)       promptstr='srv' ;;
    accounting*) promptstr='a'   ;;
    web-dev-*)   promptstr='wd'  ;;
    *)           promptstr=$(hostname -s) ;;
esac

PS1="$promptstr \$ "
```

Or just use the first three characters of the hostname:

```
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
PS1="${HOSTNAME:0:3} \$ "
```

(this requires a shell that know how to do that sort of variable substitution, obviously, but `bash` does)

... or just some other indicator to remind you that you're not local anymore, like using a `*` before the `$` (`PS1='*$ '`) remotely while not using that indicator locally. Or any other of many possible prompts.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways depending on what information you need to distinguish your machines.

---

**`dmidecode -t1`** shows information about the computer you're on, including manufacturer and model, e.g.

```
> dmidecode -t1 | grep Version
    Version: ThinkPad T520
```

---

**`uname -a`** prints system information like the network node hostname (`-n`) and the kernel release (`-r`).

---

**`lsb_release -a`** shows distribution-specific information, e.g.

```
> lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

Comment: No, hm.. sorry maybe my question was a bit abstract, I didn't mean informations about the computer, instead informations to distinguish my local from my remote computer (when using ssh sessions for instance) but thanks

Comment: @ballangddang No need to be sorry, just [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/392571/edit) your question and make it more accurate, I will do the same with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try command
 `uname -a`
OR
`hostname`, `ip a` ..etc

Answer (score 0):

write in the terminal

> hostnamectl

Comment: Technically correct, but it might be nice to show an example of its output.